# Two types of array one is string and the other is int, i want to display all the user input values but it print only the last input not all?

Tags: c#

```
namespace Test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Namen = new string[5];
            int[] Lefftijd = new int[5];
            int index=0;
            for(int i = 0; i<Namen.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Geef de naam : ");
                Namen[index] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            for(int j = 0 ; j < Lefftijd.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Geef de leeftijd : ");
                Lefftijd[index] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            Console.WriteLine("De namen zijn  " + Namen.Length + " en aantal leftijden zijn : " + Lefftijd.Length);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("De naam is : " + Namen[index] + " De leftijd is : " + Lefftijd[index]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue what language your typing the strings in but I'll give it a shot.

By the time you display the output, the index value is the last value, therefore you never display anything but the last value.

Reset index to 0 and iterate your values out.

I would use an object for the data however and just have a single array, or a list would be better. 
Rewritten below to use generics.  Hope this helps explain.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<myData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Geef de naam : ");
            var naam = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Geef de leeftijd : ");
            var leeftijd = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            data.Add(new myData(naam, leeftijd));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("De namen zijn  " + data.Count().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        data.ForEach(delegate(myData d)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("De naam is : " + d.name + " De leftijd is : " + d.age);
            //or better way
            Console.WriteLine("De naam is : {0}\tDe leftijd is : {1}", d.name, d.age);
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class myData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public myData(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing the `index` variable. I have incremented it. This is not really the best way to do this but I don't entirely understand what exactly you want to do. I hope this modification helps you see the difference.

```
namespace Test2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] Namen = new string[5];
            int[] Lefftijd = new int[5];
            int index=0;
            for(int i = 0; i<Namen.Length;i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Geef de naam : ");
                Namen[index++] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            index = 0;
            for(int j = 0 ; j < Lefftijd.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Geef de leeftijd : ");
                Lefftijd[index++] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            Console.WriteLine("De namen zijn  " + Namen.Length + " en aantal leftijden zijn : " + Lefftijd.Length);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("De naam is : " + Namen[index] + " De leftijd is : " + Lefftijd[index]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i know i must increment the index, but i tryed several ways but it also doesn't work. i want display the input of names and the input of ages in the end. the names and the ages together.